# Mobile Phone Touch Event

Tags: javascript, html, events

I want to create a slider. Here is my javascript code:

```
<div id="ghgh" style='width:50px;height:50px;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;background:#000'>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).bind('mousemove',function(ev){
$('#ghgh').offset({left:(ev.pageX-25)});});
</script>
```

This, however, only works in computers but not touch screen. I have tried to use events like touchmove,slide,scroll,etc. yet none of them works. What events should I use in order to make it work in touch screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all: put your styles and scripts in separate files.

For touch events, you may have a look at [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/)

Example from their website:

```
Hammer(el).on("swipeleft", function() {
    alert('you swiped left!');
});
```

EDIT: more specific example:

```
Hammer(document.body).on('drag', function (event) {
    var gesture = event.gesture,
        pageX = gesture.center.pageX,
        pageY = gesture.center.pageY,
        deltaX = gesture.deltaX,
        deltaY = gesture.deltaY;
    // console.log(event); Uncomment this to see all properties of the event object in your webinspector console
});
```

Comment: Can I also get the x position? (ev.pageX)

Comment: Can I replace the Hammer by $?

Comment: You should not replace `Hammer` by `$` since this could produce conflicts with other libraries like `jQuery`.

Comment: Yes you can get certain values from the event object. `Hammer(el).on("swipe", function(event){...});`. Check out the [documentation](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started);

Comment: The `event` object only contains the needed data. Calculating the positions for the slidable elements is your own job.

Comment: However, without calculating pageX position the slider cannot work. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Since a touch can be done with multiple fingers, there is not a single pageX/Y value, but an array `event.touches` of "touches". Just `console.log` the `event` object out and you'll see, you have all informations needed. Check out their [documentation](https://github.com/EightMedia/hammer.js/wiki/Getting-Started#event-data)